# How can i access my controller located in "folder_name/controller_name" in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

> My Master controller located in "admin" folder. View image
>   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRtLl.png)

```
namespace App\Controllers\admin;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
class Master extends Controller
{
function __construct(){
helper('url');
}
public function index()
{
$data["content"]="view_home";
echo view('template/template', $data);
}
}
```

> In my Routes.php i added this

```
$routes->get('admin/master','Master::index',['namespace','App\Controllers\admin']);
```

> when i access the page in the browser i get this error

404 - File Not Found
Controller or its method is not found: {0}::{1}

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My silly mistake when setting up the route. I've put a "," instead of "=>". See the correct route below.

```
$routes->get('admin/master','Master::index',['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\admin']);
```